# Firebase User does not get notified when a message has been sent

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple chat app where users can register, login and send messages to other users that is displayed in a list view but the problem for example, is that when user 4 send a message to user 22 , there is no way of informing user 22 of a new message if he is not on the chat activity. User 22 might be on chat with user 16 and the 4 send a message to 22, I would like to display a toast informing user 22 that there has been a new message. below is my data base structure and code.

```
messages
Esetara_Franklyn
-NDzI5wqxZ0K9Jk-vHK4
Franklyn_Esetara
-NDzI5xERPCib339DbsZ
Franklyn_eduwa
-NDrJnBPS3C6IiIcWTrk
-NDrK_IhpotaQYwk2w6U
-NDrbBYkNlBoKVn8UJym
-NDsHeUFdo2mJ3rJfa2H
-NDy18HTYbYR-GZZZGL1
eduwa_Franklyn
-NDrJnBhXpXNsq8jk-DO
-NDrK_IwuynathoY95BF
-NDrbBZ3k0S5EN28h4kZ
-NDsHeUejqb9xoxQkcKt
-NDy18Hfcs7_FspVs0zR

users
Esetara
Franklyn
eduwa
```

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
//please note that the firebase link has be chagned for security reasons
        reference1 = new Firebase("https://chat-b6b84-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/messages/" + UserDetails.username + "_" + UserDetails.chatWith);
        reference2 = new Firebase("https://chat-b6b84-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/messages/" + UserDetails.chatWith + "_" + UserDetails.username);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String messageText = messageArea.getText().toString();

                if(!messageText.equals("")){
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("message", messageText);
                    map.put("user", UserDetails.username);
                    reference1.push().setValue(map);
                    reference2.push().setValue(map);
                    messageArea.setText("");
                }

            }
        });
 reference1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Map map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                String message = map.get("message").toString();
                String userName = map.get("user").toString();
                
                if(userName.equals(UserDetails.username)){
                    addMessageBox(message, 1);
                }
                else{
                    addMessageBox(message, 2);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
public void addMessageBox(String message, int type){
        TextView textView = new TextView(Chat.this);
        textView.setText(message);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp2.weight = 7.0f;

        if(type == 1) {
            lp2.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_in);
            textView.setMaxWidth(450);
        }
        else{
            lp2.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_out);
            textView.setMaxWidth(450);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        layout.addView(textView);
        scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code, i just want to know when a new message is received.  for example when I am chatting with another user (Franklyn_eduwa) and then i get messaged by (Esetara_Franklyn) . How will i know that there has been a new message?